# Help over the proof of triple vector product identity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, cross-product

For all vectors $\bf{x}$, $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$,

$$\bf{x}\times(\bf{y}\times\bf{z})=(\bf{x}\cdot\bf{z})\bf{y}-(\bf{x}\cdot\bf{y})\bf{z}$$

The proof goes as follows:

We may suppose that $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$ lie along different lines through
the origin, for otherwise it is is trivially true. Then any $\bf{x}$ can be written as a
linear combination of $\bf{y}$,$\bf{z}$ and $\bf{y}\times\bf{z}$. As both sides are linear in $\bf{x}$, it is only necessary to verify the identity when $\bf{x}$ is each of these three vectors.

$\bigg[$1. My first question, why? Why is it only necessary to verify these three possibilities?$\bigg]$

When $\bf{x}=\bf{y}\times\bf{z}$ all terms are zero, so it is true. The two cases $\bf{x}=\bf{y}$ and $\bf{x}=\bf{z}$ are the same (apart from a factor −1 on each side of the equation), so we have reduced our task to giving a proof of the identity

$$\bf{y}\times(\bf{y}\times\bf{z})=(\bf{y}\cdot\bf{z})\bf{y}-(\bf{y}\cdot\bf{y})\bf{z}$$

for all $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$.

Now the latter is true when $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$ lie along the same line through the origin. Thus, as both sides of the latter identity are linear in $\bf{z}$, it only remains to prove this when $\bf{z}$ is orthogonal to $\bf{y}$.

$\bigg[$2. Now few questions at this stage: how does the author determines that both sides are linear in $\bf{z}$ and why does it only remain to prove it when $\bf{z}$ is orthogonal to $\bf{y}$?$\bigg]$

Moreover, it is clearly sufficient to prove this when $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$ are unit vectors. Now $\bf{y}\times(\bf{y}\times\bf{z})$ is of length one and also a scalar multiple
of $\bf{z}$. Thus it is $\pm\bf{z}$, so if we let $\mu=\bf{z}\cdot[\bf{y}\times(\bf{y}\times\bf{z})]$, then $\mu=\pm1$. However, $\mu$ is clearly a continuous function of the coefficients of $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$, so it must be independent of
$\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$.

$\bigg[$3. What do he mean by clearly continuous function independent of $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$?$\bigg]$

As $\mu = −1$ when $\bf{y}=\bf{i}$ and $\bf{z}=\bf{j}$ , we see that $\bf{y}\times(\bf{y}\times\bf{z})=-\bf{z}$ and the proof is complete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you interested in explanation of the proof above only?  Because I have other, shorter and more elegant one using index notation.

Comment: exactly. the point is not how to prove this, but how to understand the given proof. I realize it's not as elegant as some others, but I feel I need to understand it to be able to follow further content :)

Comment: @Kaster What's interesting about this proof is that it seems to reason around coordinates, (completely?) for the most part. I actually find that more preferable than resorting to indices. Still, I would love to see your proof :) Can you stick it in a comment here?

Comment: @Sarunas Where does this proof appear?

Comment: Thanks for answers! it appeared in Beardon's Geometry and Algebra :)

Comment: @rschwieb, no problem.
$$
\fbox{$[\mathbf x \times (\mathbf y \times \mathbf z)]_i$} = \epsilon_{ijk}x_j (\mathbf y \times \mathbf z)_k = \epsilon_{ijk} x_j \epsilon_{kmn} y_mz_n = (\delta_{im} \delta_{jn} - \delta_{in} \delta_{jm})x_jy_mz_n = \\
= x_jy_iz_j - x_jy_jz_i = \fbox{$[(\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf z)\mathbf y]_i - [(\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y)\mathbf z]_i$}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) In $\mathbf{R}^3$ the vector system  $\bf{y},\bf{z},\bf{y}\times\bf{z}$ is a basis (supposing that $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$ lie along different lines through the origin).
So if you want to check the equality of two linear maps it is enough to check for basis vectors.

2.) Putting $\bf{z}:=\bf{z}_1+\alpha\bf{z}_2$ and using the linearity of cross product (vector product) and inner product you obtain the linearity of the mentioned expressions. When $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}$ do not lie along the same line through the origin, then you can decompose (uniquely) $\bf{z}=\bf{z}_{||}+\bf{z}_{\perp}$, where $\bf{z}_{||}$ is parallel to $\bf{y}$ and $\bf{z}_{\perp}$ is perpendicular (orthogonal) to $\bf{y}$.

3.) Sorry :-) I don't understand this continuity argument. Hopefully someone else can help you to make clear this last step.

Answer (score 2):

I'll help out with #3, since vesszabo gave satisfactory answers to the first two.

Since addition and multiplication operations in $\Bbb R^3$ are continuous operations, then any manner of finite compositions of these operations creates a continuous map. So, what we have here is a continuous map $U \to \{-1,1\}$ where $U$ is the unit sphere from the unit sphere $U\subset\Bbb R^3$.

But, the author notes, you have an example of something that maps to $-1$.  Therefore *everything* in $U$ maps to $-1$: otherwise you have discontinuity. $U$ is a connected set, and a continuous image of $U$ can't get split into two pieces going into both $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. (+1)
The original proof is very clever.